# Golang SQL query syntax validator

Tags: sql, validation, go, syntax

Is there any third-party tool for validate SQL query before I execute it with the database/sql pacakge or any way to check the SQL query is right without getting a panic from database/sql that the query is invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found [this SQL parser](https://github.com/xwb1989/sqlparser) package. I colud use it for validate it.

```
func isSQLValid(sql string) (bool, error) {
    _, err := sqlparser.Parse(sql)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Comment: It only supports MySQL SQL